# Most efficient way to reallocate while ordering values in memory?

Tags: c, malloc, memcpy, realloc

I have 32 bytes of contiguous memory allocated (using `malloc`) to hold eight sequential 32 bit values. After certain tasks have been performed on this piece of memory, The values are laid out like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| d |   |   |   |   | a | b | c |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Notice there's a hole? These values are no longer needed and can be disregarded. The hole will always be half the size of the main allocation and always contiguous.

What is the most efficient and fastest way of reallocating this piece of memory while also re-ordering the values to be like this?

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Comment: Does the hole start at [1] everytime? Is the abc-part at the end always sorted?

Comment: The hole can start at different offsets and the values are always sorted in a circular fashion.

Comment: Do you have performance problems with two `memcpy`s?

Comment: Is that hole contains some sentinel value?

Comment: I haven't implemented anything yet and i'm mulling over how to do it. What i want to avoid is allocating separate temporary buffers. I'm sure everything can be reshuffled in-place then reallocated.

Comment: If the number of elements (of the whole array) is even, and the hole is at least half as big as the buffer (and there are no holes at the beginning or end), you can safely copy `d` and then `a … c`.

Comment: Yes but copy to where? I'm trying to avoid unnecessary buffers.

Comment: Are you only interested in a general C solution or can it be architecture-specific?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on mafso's answer i ended going with this solution using one `memmove` and one `memcpy`.

Start:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| d |   |   |   |   | a | b | c |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

`memmove` the first element(s) to the right:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| d |   |   | d |   | a | b | c |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

`memcpy` the end element(s) to the beginning:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |   | a | b | c |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Then `realloc` to shorten:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Simple and profiles very fast.

Comment: Of course it´s simple, but if you want a simple *short* solution, then ask not for the *fastest* ...

Comment: This is simple and short and is much more generic than your proposal in that it deals with arbitrary lengths. Hard coding indexes, while fast, is a pretty poor solution over all. This actually profiles very fast too.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the simplest possible code, making it easy for the compiler to optimize. A good compiler (or even a bad one, TBH) has a much better chance of coming up with the fastest assembly for the platform in use than I do.

So, for example (malloc/realloc error checking excluded for brevity):

```
uint32_t *buf = malloc(32);

// your operations here

buf[3] = buf[0];
buf[0] = buf[5];
buf[1] = buf[6];
buf[2] = buf[7];

// optional obviously, waste of time if that 16 bytes isn't a dealbreaker
buf = realloc(buf, 16);
```

Comment: "The hole can start at different offsets". Well, +1 anyways.

Comment: @deviantfan the question didn't say that (although I see now it appears in the comments). I guess if we're given the hole's location (in which case we could switch on it. If we have to search for the hole then more info is needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
uint32_t *values;
if(offset == 0)
{
    values[0] = values[4];
    values[1] = values[5];
    values[2] = values[6];
    values[3] = values[7];
}
else if(offset == 1)
{
    values[3] = values[0];
    values[0] = values[5];
    values[1] = values[6];
    values[2] = values[7];
}
else if(offset == 2)
{
    values[2] = values[0];
    values[3] = values[1];
    values[0] = values[6];
    values[1] = values[7];
}
else if(offset == 3)
{
    values[3] = values[2];
    values[2] = values[1];
    values[1] = values[0];
    values[0] = values[7];
}
```

I know, a really "stupid" solution.
But everything containing as much as a single memmove with a variable parameter
won´t come anywhere close in terms of speed for me (and modulo...eh, yeah.)

Comment: I deleted my answer, not by your criticism agains my "mod" approach, but because I commite a mistake reading "32 eight-bit values", but the OP said "eight 32-bit values".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming an even number of 32-bit values in the whole array (and 8 is even), something like the following should work:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <stdio.h>

void re_sort_buffer(uint32_t *arr, size_t head_len, size_t hole_len, size_t tail_len) {
    memmove(arr+hole_len-head_len, arr, head_len*sizeof *arr); // see below
    memcpy(arr, arr+head_len+hole_len, tail_len*sizeof *arr);
}

int main(void) {
    uint32_t test[] = { 'b', 'c', 'd', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'a' };
    re_sort_buffer(test, 3, 4, 1);
    for(size_t i=0; i < 3+4+1; ++i) printf("'%c' ", test[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Output:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' '*' '*' '*' 'a'
```

You may want to hard-code some parameters of `re_sort_buffer` or pass different parameters etc.

Iff `hole_len` - `head_len` ≥ `head_len` (equivalently, iff `hole_len`÷2 (in your case 2) ≥ `head_len`), you can avoid using `memmove` by using `memcpy` instead; otherwise, I don't see a better way. Perhaps it's better to use a temporary buffer in this case; I think, everything further will be platform-specific.

HTH